# How to Extract url address from excel cell using C# MS Interop

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink, interop

I have been trying to get the hyperlinks from cells on a file I'm reading in. The problem I'm having is that I have not been able to extract the entire address not sure what the syntax is or what's the miss. I'm using C# and MS interop since due to company policy cannot use 3rd party pkgs. have tried the below code as a test and it only pulls partially the embedded address from the specified cell.

I've tried something along these lines. Console.Write(excelRange.Cells[3, 2].hyperlinks(1).Address); but it doesn't return the whole address, only partial http://somewebsite.com/app

when the whole address is format is :  http://somewebsite.com/app #/morethings-1/somemorethings/information-743028
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
using Excel= Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;    
var excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("path_to_file");
var worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"]; 
string cellValue = (worksheet.Cells[2, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
Console.Write(cellValue);
```

The above gives me the full value as we are obtaining the value from the cell and not the address of the hyperlink. I think when the hyperlink was constructed something was wrong with the address. The address is not the same as the text in the cell.

Address =>  http://somewebsite.com/app

CellValue =>  http://somewebsite.com/app #/morethings-1/somemorethings/information-743028

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. in reality there is nothing wrong with the link. and I'm not trying to get the value of the cell. I need to extract the address value not the visible text value which differs from its hyperlink that is attached. I'm not sure how to add an image here to help show what I'm talking about.

but if you looked at the details for the cell it would be

**Text to display** : 1.0.33.141349  **Address:** http://deploy.something.com/app#/Spaces-1/deployments/Deployments-741156

Thanks